# How to show $T(\rho,\sigma)≥\sum_i|r_i − s_i|$ with $r_i,s_i$ eigenvalues of $\rho,\sigma$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, information-theory, entropy, trace-distance

The proof of the Fannes' inequality replies on the formula $T(ρ, σ)≥\sum_i|r_i − s_i|$, where $r_i,s_i$ are the eigenvalues of $\rho,\sigma$, in the descending order.

In the proof given in [Box 11.2, Page 512, Chapter 8, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), it is given that

By the spectral decomposition, we may decompose $\rho−\sigma=Q−R$, where $Q$ and $R$ are positive operators with orthogonal support, so $T (\rho,\sigma)=tr(R)+tr(Q)$. Defining $V\equiv R+\rho=Q+\sigma$, we have $T (\rho, \sigma) = tr(R) + tr(Q) = tr(2V ) − tr(\rho) − tr(\sigma)$. Let $t_1\geq t_2\geq · · · \geq t_d$ be the eigenvalues of $T$. Note that $t_i\geq \max(r_i,s_i )$, so $2t_i\geq r_i + s_i + |r_i−s_i |$, and it follows that
$$
T(\rho,\sigma)\geq|r_i − s_i|
$$

---

**My understanding**

Let $H=\rho-\sigma$, which is hermitian since both $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are positive semidefinite.

The spectral decomposition of $H$ can be written as, $H=\rho-\sigma=VD_HV^\dagger$.

Let $D_Q$ be the diagonal matrix that has all the positive eigenvalues of $H$, and $D_R$ contains the negation of all the negative eigenvalues of $H$, such that we can define $VD_QV^\dagger=Q$ and $VD_RV^\dagger=R$. Therefore,
$$
D_H=D_Q-D_R\\
H=\rho-\sigma=VD_HV^\dagger=V(D_Q-D_R)V^\dagger=VD_QV^\dagger-VD_RV^\dagger=Q-R
$$
$\implies D_Q,D_R$, and thereby $Q,R$ have orthogonal supports, since $Q$ only supports the positive eigenspace and $R$ only supports the negative eigenspace.

$\therefore D_QD_R=D_RD_Q=0\implies QR=RQ=0$

So we have, $\rho-\sigma=Q-R$, where $Q$ and $R$ are positive operators with orthogonal supports.

The trace distance between $\rho$ and $\sigma$ is defined as, $T(\rho,\sigma)=\dfrac{1}{2}tr|\rho-\sigma|=\dfrac{1}{2}tr\sqrt{(\rho-\sigma)^\dagger(\rho-\sigma)}$
\begin{align}
(\rho-\sigma)^\dagger(\rho-\sigma)&=(Q-R)^\dagger(Q-R)=(Q^\dagger-R^\dagger)(Q-R)\\
&=Q^\dagger Q+R^\dagger R-Q^\dagger R-R^\dagger Q\\
&=QQ+RR-QR-RQ=Q^2+R^2\text{ , since }QR=RQ=0\\
&=QQ+RR+QR+RQ=(Q+R)^2\\
\sqrt{(\rho-\sigma)^\dagger(\rho-\sigma)}&=Q+R
\end{align}
So the trace distance becomes $T(\rho,\sigma)=\dfrac{1}{2}tr(Q+R)=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big(tr(Q)+tr(R)\Big)$

Defining $V\equiv R+\rho=Q+\sigma$ obtains $2T(\rho,\sigma)=tr(Q)+tr(R)=tr(2V)-tr(\rho)-tr(\sigma)$

> How do I proceed further to obtain $T(\rho,\sigma)\ge\sum_i|r_i − s_i|$? Or is it rather $2T(\rho,\sigma)\ge\sum_i|r_i − s_i|$?

**Min-Max theorem**

The Rayleigh quotient for any vector $|x\rangle$ is defined to be the ratio $r(x)=\dfrac{\langle x|V|x\rangle}{\langle x|x\rangle}$, where $r(x)$ is scaling invariant, ie., $r(tx)=\dfrac{\langle tx|V|tx\rangle}{\langle tx|tx\rangle}=\dfrac{t^2\langle x|V|x\rangle}{t^2\langle x|x\rangle}=\dfrac{\langle x|V|x\rangle}{\langle x|x\rangle}=r(x)$

$\therefore$ it is sufficient to study the special case $\langle x|x\rangle=1$, so that the critical points of the function $\dfrac{\langle x|V|x\rangle}{\langle x|x\rangle}$ is the same as that of $\langle x|V|x\rangle$ subjected to the constraint ${\langle x|x\rangle}=1$.

We can prove that the critical points of $r(x)$ are the eigenvectors $|u_i\rangle$ of the operator $V$. Therefore, $t_{\min}=\min_{u\neq 0}r(u)$ and $t_{\max}=\max_{u\neq 0}r(u)$.

If $t_1\geq t_2\geq \cdots\geq t_k\geq\cdots\geq t_d$ be the eigenvalues of $V$ in the descending order then this implies

\begin{align}
t_d&=\min_{u\neq 0}r(u)=\min_{x\neq 0}\{r(x):|x\rangle\in U\text{ and }\dim(U)=d\}\\
t_{d-1}&=\min_{u\neq 0\in u_d^\perp}r(u)=\max\{\min_{x\neq 0}\{r(x):|x\rangle\in U\text{ and }\dim(U)=d-1\}\}\\
\vdots\\
t_{k}&=\min_{u\neq 0\in \{u_d,u_{d-1},\cdots, u_{k+1}\}^\perp}r(u)\\
&=\max\{\min_{x\neq 0}\{r(x):|x\rangle\in U\text{ and }\dim(U)=k\}\}\\
&=\max\{\min_{x\neq 0}\{\langle x|V|x\rangle:|x\rangle\in U\text{ and }\dim(U)=k\}\}\\
&=\max\{min_{x\neq 0}\{\langle x|R+\rho|x\rangle:|x\rangle\in U\text{ and }\dim(U)=k\}\}\\
&=\max\{\min_{x\neq 0}\{\langle x|R|x\rangle+\langle x|\rho|x\rangle:|x\rangle\in U\text{ and }\dim(U)=k\}\}\\
&\geq\max\{\min_{x\neq 0}\{\langle x|\rho|x\rangle:|x\rangle\in U\text{ and }\dim(U)=k\}\}\\
&=r_k
\end{align}

Comment: isn't this the same as https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/29563/55?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem), we have$^1$
$$
\begin{align}
t_k&=\max_{\quad U\\\dim U=k}\min_{|x\rangle\in U\\\langle x|x\rangle=1}\langle x|V|x\rangle\tag1\\
&=\max_{\quad U\\\dim U=k}\min_{|x\rangle\in U\\\langle x|x\rangle=1}\left[\langle x|R|x\rangle+\langle x|\rho|x\rangle\right]\tag2\\
&\ge\max_{\quad U\\\dim U=k}\min_{|x\rangle\in U\\\langle x|x\rangle=1}\langle x|\rho|x\rangle\tag3\\
&=r_k\tag4
\end{align}
$$
where we used $V:=R+\rho$ and the fact that $R$ is positive semi-definite. This is a rigorous statement of the intuitive fact that adding a positive semi-definite operator cannot reduce eigenvalues. Since $V=Q+\sigma$, an analogous argument gives us $t_k\ge s_k$. Therefore,
$$
2t_k\ge2\max(r_k, s_k)=r_k+s_k+|r_k-s_k|.\tag5
$$
This allows us to bound the trace distance $2T(\rho,\sigma)=\mathrm{tr}(2V)-\mathrm{tr}(\rho)-\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)$ as follows
$$
\begin{align}
2T(\rho,\sigma)&=\mathrm{tr}(2V)-\mathrm{tr}(\rho)-\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)\tag6\\
&=\left(\sum_k2t_k\right)-\mathrm{tr}(\rho)-\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)\tag7\\
&\ge\left(\sum_kr_k+s_k+|r_k-s_k|\right)-\mathrm{tr}(\rho)-\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)\tag8\\
&=\left(\mathrm{tr}(\rho)+\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)+\sum_k|r_k-s_k|\right)-\mathrm{tr}(\rho)-\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)\tag9\\
&=\sum_k|r_k-s_k|.\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
This agrees with your expectation that $2T(\rho,\sigma)\ge\sum_k|r_k-s_k|$ rather than $T(\rho,\sigma)\ge\sum_k|r_k-s_k|$ as in $(11.46)$ in Nielsen & Chuang. It appears there is a mistake in Nielsen & Chuang which you can confirm by comparing to the [article in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fannes%E2%80%93Audenaert_inequality). Also, compare to the last paragraph on page $404$ where a similar argument is made without the error. Finally, we can see that $(11.46)$ cannot be true by substituting $\rho=|0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $\sigma=\frac{I}{2}$. It looks as if box $11.2$ might be using $T(\rho,\sigma):=\|\rho-\sigma\|_1$ without the $\frac12$ factor.

---

$^1$ There is a typo box $11.2$. It says

> Let $t_1\ge t_2\ge \dots\ge t_d$ be the eigenvalues of $T.$

but it should read

> Let $t_1\ge t_2\ge \dots\ge t_d$ be the eigenvalues of $V.$

Note that $T$ denotes the trace distance which is not a linear function and hence doesn't have eigenvalues.

Comment: $T(\rho,\sigma)=\dfrac{1}{2}tr(Q)+\dfrac{1}{2}tr(R)\implies 2T(\rho,\sigma)=tr(Q)+tr(R)$. Defining $V\equiv R+\rho=Q+\sigma$ then $\color{red}{2}T(\rho,\sigma)=tr(V-\sigma)+tr(V-\rho)=2tr(V)-tr(\rho)-tr(\sigma)$, right ?

Comment: Indeed! Good catch! See my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rephrasing of the same approach to the proof, using a slightly different notation.

You want to prove that
$$T(\rho,\sigma) \equiv \frac12\|\rho-\sigma\|_1 \ge \frac12\sum_k |\lambda_k(\rho) - \lambda_k(\sigma)|,$$
where $\lambda_k^\downarrow(A)$ is the $k$-th largest eigenvalue of $A$.

1. For a generic Hermitian matrix $A$, denote with $(A)_+$ and $(A)_-$ its positive and negative parts, that is, the (unique) positive-definite matrices such that $A=A_+-A_-$ and $A_+ A_-=0$.
2. Observe that
   $$\|\rho-\sigma\|_1=\sum_k |\lambda_k^\downarrow(\rho-\sigma)| =
   2 \sum_k \lambda_k^\downarrow((\rho-\sigma)_+) =
   2 \sum_k \lambda_k^\downarrow((\rho-\sigma)_-).$$
   In words, I'm saying that $\|\rho-\sigma\|_1$, which by definition is the sum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $\rho-\sigma$, also equals (half of) the sum of the eigenvalues of the *positive* (*negative*) part of $\rho-\sigma$. This relies on the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(\rho-\sigma)=0$. An equivalent way to write the above is
   $$\|\rho-\sigma\|_1 = 2\operatorname{tr}[(\rho-\sigma)_\pm].$$
3. Consider now a generic pair of PSD operators $A,B\ge0$. Then
   $$\operatorname{tr}[(A-B)_+]
   = \operatorname{tr}[(A-B)_+ + A] - \operatorname{tr}(A), \\
   \lambda_k^\downarrow((A-B)_\pm + A) \ge \lambda_k^\downarrow(A),
   \qquad
   \lambda_k^\downarrow((A-B)_\pm + B) \ge \lambda_k^\downarrow(B).$$
   The last two equations are shown using the technique with the minimax theorem discussed in [the other answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29598/55).

   Applying this to our operators, because $\rho+(\rho-\sigma)_- = \sigma+(\rho-\sigma)_+$, we get
   $$\operatorname{tr}[(\rho-\sigma)_\pm] =
   \operatorname{tr}[\rho+(\rho-\sigma)_-] - 1
   = \sum_k \lambda_k^\downarrow(\rho + (\rho-\sigma)_- ) - 1,\\
   \lambda_k^\downarrow(\rho + (\rho-\sigma)_- ) \ge \max(\lambda_k^\downarrow(\rho),\lambda_k^\downarrow(\sigma)),$$
   and using the standard algebraic identity $2\max(a,b)=a+b+|a-b|$, we conclude that
   $$\operatorname{tr}[\rho+(\rho-\sigma)_-] \ge
   1 + \frac12\sum_k |\lambda_k^\downarrow(\rho)-\lambda_k^\downarrow(\sigma)|,$$
   hence the statement at issue.